Click on a Selenium button that isn't an input
I've the following HTML code:
<div _ngcontent-fsi-c26="" class="col-xs-12 ng-star-inserted" style="margin-top: 3%;">
                            <div _ngcontent-fsi-c26="" class=" col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-4">
                                <button _ngcontent-fsi-c26="" buttontype="secondary" spaui-button-custom="" type="button" class="spaui-button secondary"><!---->
<!---->
<!---->
<!---->CONSULTAR PRODUTO<!----></button>
                            </div>
                            <!----><div _ngcontent-fsi-c26="" class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-4 ng-star-inserted">
                                <button _ngcontent-fsi-c26="" buttontype="primary" spaui-button-custom="" type="button" class="spaui-button primary"><!---->
<!---->
<!---->
<!---->CANCELAR PRODUTO<!----></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

What I've been trying to achieve: Of course I didn't post the entire HTML code, too much. However, this button interacts with a radio button on a table. Considering the manual process, I would click on the radio button (to select the option) and then click on the button with the text "CONSULTAR PRODUTO". Here's the code I've been using to reach the button.
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("accordion-tab-body")); //After clicking on an accordion it expands a table with all the data I need.
var accordionData = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div > spaui-datatable > table > tbody")); //Navigating to the table to get its elements
var rows = accordionData.FindElements(By.CssSelector("tr")); //Each table row. Ignoring table head, not interesting right now


foreach(var currData in rows)
{
    var lines = currData.FindElements(By.CssSelector("td"));
    foreach(var currTd in lines)
    {
        if(currTd.Text == "") //If the text is blank, means the first element - which is the radio button icon
        {
            currTd.Click(); //Radio selected
            var consultarProdutoBtn = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div > div > div > button")); //The related button was found (I think).
            consultarProdutoBtn.Click(); //Where it crashes.

        }
    }
}

However I'm always getting an exception saying the element isn't interactable.
I don't have any  tags along the HTML code, neither submit. All I have is this button.
I've read a lot of sites on SO (that's why I managed to get so far) but I still can't click this button.
Something I've thought of was to get its location and click by using JavaScript on its coordinates. Could this be a proper solution?
I would basically need to get the button with the text "CONSULTAR PRODUTO" and click on it. I've also tried to reach the button by using its XPath:
 var consultarProdutoButton = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[contains(text(), 'CONSULTAR PRODUTO')]"));
                consultarProdutoButton.Click();

But this didn't worked either.
Any input is appreciated, thanks a lot.

Did you try using the buttontype value as your locator ? It’s generally a bad practice to rely on text based locators.

Wait for element to be clickable before click on the button and try to click. It may solve the issue.

I've tried waiting for the element to be clickable ... don't know why but the element isn't valid on the page (aka its clickable but nothing will happen).
So, this doesn't work. I've figured out another way of doing what i need - posted in the answer below =)

I've figured it out.
In order to reach my button, this is what i did:
 var btnConsultar = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//button[@class='spaui-button secondary']"));
 btnConsultar.ElementAt(1).SendKeys(Keys.Enter); //Element 1 is the "Consultar Produto" button

By doing so i managed to find the button on the webpage, and "Click" on it.
However i'm gonna try later the buttontype locator, as suggested on the comments.
Thanks in advance!
